# Macbook 2020 with intel chips, setting up wifi for Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, macbook-pro

I am a beginner in Ubuntu and I just set up the Ubuntu environment. I am trying to set up wifi for my Macbook pro-2020(with intel core chips).
Here is some details that shows up when I run the command lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network on terminal:

```
e5:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4364 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4464] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4364 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [106b:07bf]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort+ <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at 81400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Region 2: Memory at 81000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: brcmfmac, wl

e6:00.0 Mass storage controller [0180]: Apple Inc. ANS2 NVMe Controller [106b:2005] (rev 01) (prog-if 02)
```

So I follow this link [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) but I could  not find my pci id on the table. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it uses T2, you're better off running this: https://t2linux.org/